# Covariation of density process in Girsanov's Theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

I am reading a proof of the following theorem concerning Girsanov's Theorem.

> Let be $M$ a continuous local $P$- martingale. Then $M-\langle M,Y\rangle$ is a continuos local $Q$ martingale.

Here $Y_t=\int_0^t\frac{1}{Z_s}dZ_s$ and $Z_t$ is the radon nikodym density $\frac{dQ}{dP}_{\mid F_t}$.
I do not understand the following part in the proof:

> Why is $\int_0^t\frac{1}{Z_s}d\langle M,Z\rangle=\langle M,Y\rangle_t$ true?

Any help here is highly appreciated.

The original proof:

From $Z_t=Z_0\exp(Y_t-\frac12\langle Y\rangle_t$ we have $dZ_t=Z_tdY_t$ thus $$(\frac {1}{Z}\circ \langle M,Z\rangle)_t=\int_0^t\frac{1}{Z_s}Z_sd\langle M,Y\rangle_s=\langle M,Y\rangle$$

Comment: do you have a reference for the proof?

Comment: @RScrilli the proof is in imediate consequence of Girsanov. I edited the proof. I see why this proof works, but I do not see the equality sign. Can you help me here?

Comment: I can give you a proof for the theorem, still I wanted to see the proof you were using so I can follow the reasoning your proof is using

Comment: I just need to understand the first  equality sign. Do you understand this and could elaborate on it ?

Comment: It follows from Kunita-Watanabe characterization: $[H \bullet M,N]=H \bullet [M,N].$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heuristically $$dZ=YdY$$
implies that $$\frac{dZ}{Z}=dY.$$

Then $$dM\frac{dZ}{Z}=dY dM$$
which is equivalent to $\frac{1}{Z} d\langle Z,M\rangle=d\langle Y,M\rangle$.
Integrating both sides gives the desired result